# polars datetime 5 minutes floor

Tags: python, timestamp, python-polars, floor

I have polars dataframe with timestamp folumn of type datetime[ns] which value is `2023-03-08 11:13:07.831`
I want to use polars efficiency to round timestamp to 5 minutes floor.

Right now I do:

```
import arrow

def timestamp_5minutes_floor(ts: int) -> int:
    return int(arrow.get(ts).timestamp() // 300000 * 300000)

df.with_columns([
    pl.col("timestamp").apply(lambda x: timestamp_5minutes_floor(x)).alias("ts_floor")
    ])
```

It is slow. How to improve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use [`.dt.truncate`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.truncate.html): With the sample dataframe

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "ts": ["2023-03-08 11:01:07.831", "2023-03-08 18:09:01.007"]
}).select(pl.col("ts").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%.3f"))
```

```
┌─────────────────────────┐
│ ts                      │
│ ---                     │
│ datetime[ms]            │
╞═════════════════════════╡
│ 2023-03-08 11:01:07.831 │
│ 2023-03-08 18:09:01.007 │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

this

```py
df = df.select(pl.col("ts").dt.truncate("5m"))
```

results in

```
┌─────────────────────┐
│ ts                  │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[ms]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2023-03-08 11:00:00 │
│ 2023-03-08 18:05:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Is there something similar to `ceil`?

Comment: @Thomas I haven't seen a native Polars method for this. You could use the `offset` argument of `.truncate` to shift upward, but that won't work for items that don't change with the truncation. A workaround could be (for the 5 minutes in the example): setting `unit = 300_000_000` and then doing `df.select(pl.col("ts").dt.timestamp().truediv(unit).ceil().mul(unit).cast(pl.Datetime))`.